# Combine multiple Booleans and Check if any are true in python

Tags: python, boolean

Title is pretty self explanatory. I want a condition to be satisfied if any of 16 different variables are true, but I feel like there has to be a better/cleaner way to do it than typing out if A = True or B = True ....  etc etc. Is there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
any([A, B, ...])
```

Comment: Or the shorter `any([A, B, ...])` In Python you rarely want to do direct comparisons with `True` or `False`.

Comment: wouldn't that be for and, not or? Checking if all the variables are true? I want to check if ANY of the variables are true.

Comment: @user2765554 Yea, I changed it to `any()`.

Comment: The i for i generator is redundant.

Comment: @Wooble On second thoughts, that of course makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check to see if ALL of the boolean variables are true, do the following:

```
 if all([length, zero_to_255, all_nums]) == True:
        print("Valid IP Address")
```